# Convert Items of a List/Dictionary to the first column of a 2D Array VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty new to VBA here and would like some help.

So, I have a dictionary containing 3600 items and another pre-defined array with 3600 rows and 4 columns. 
How can I move all items from the dict to the first column of the array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop through all the keys/items of your dictionary and assign  them to your array.

Comment: Your mistake is to use a 2 dimensional array.  You may be better off using a collection of arrays or an arraylist of arraylists.  Then you could just do myCollection.item(0)=dict.items.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple and you should be able to do it if you have created your dictionary and your array...

See below code. Loop through your dictionary and add the items to the array.

```vb
For i = 1 to myDict.Count
    myArr(i,1) = myDict(i)
Next i
```